# How to use “ available”

Tags: meaning

Place of available in sentence confused me . I wrote some sentences by using avaliable in different places. Are all sentences same meaning or changing place makes meaning diffrent ?

> I have available 25 packs of pen.
>
> I have 25 packs available of pen.
>
> I have 25 packs of pen available.

Answer (score 1):

Well, it should be *pens*, plural, but that's not the point of your question.

All three are potentially okay in certain circumstances, though the second one only makes sense to me as dialogue, representing an afterthought:

> "I have 25 packs available. Of pens."

That isn't grammatical as written English, but people speak that way.

The first and third are both perfectly fine in any case, but the third is the more usual syntax. The first would mostly be used by someone trying to sell things, or promote things. It's a showman's sort of phrasing.

Answer (score 0):

The final sentence is by far the best sentence that sounds natural, and is the most common place in which to use the word 'available'. The other two sentences, although people would understand what you are trying to say, would not be grammatically correct.

Also, in English, you would not say 'packs of pen' because 'pack' is a collective noun that refers to a group of items. Therefore, you would use 'packs of pens' in place of 'packs of pen.

Comment: Oh, the first option is valid and idiomatic, just not for everyday usage.